# What type of nonstick pan is this?

Tags: equipment, frying-pan, non-stick

I need a new nonstick pan. I saw a video with a pan which looks good to me. The person in the video didn't grease or oil at all, and her pancake didn't stick to the pan. She could flip her pancakes perfectly.

[image: pan snapshot]

This is a snapshot of the pan. Can you please identify the type of pan, so I can search for similar pans?

Comment: I would like to remind all who want to post that this is not a question on general buying advice for pan types; this would be a duplicate. Just answer with your identification of the pan in the picture, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the extent that it can be told from a picture, probably "ceramic" coated **if** it's non-stick coated at all. Might just be seasoned carbon steel. It certainly shines like oil was applied, perhaps off-camera, but if not, that might be due to shiny ceramic.

However, the various black marks are more typical of stuff burnt onto a steel pan that shines due to oil than a clean enough to be shiny ceramic pan.

Odds are excellent that the oil you didn't see being added to the pan is in the batter - there are many tricks without even getting into the the ones requiring video editing. Plenty of folks can manage the "flipping pancakes" level of "non-stick" with a cast-iron pan. One aspect of that is making sure it's hot enough before the batter hits it. Oil in the batter is another.

Comment: You appear to need [this original video on Bilibili](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3779) to answer this question. Does it change your answer?